# Customize "return by value" in IntEnum

Tags: python, enums, integer, overriding

I have a class that extends `IntEnum` class that defines positions in a bit-encoded variable:

```
from enum import IntEnum

class Bits(IntEnum):

    @classmethod
    def data(cls, value: int):
        return [ e for e in cls if (1 << e) & value ]

class Status(Bits):
    READY = 0
    ERROR = 1
    WARNING = 2

x = Status.data(3) # x <- [<Status.READY: 0>, <Status.ERROR: 1>]
y = Status.data(4) # y <- [<Status.WARNING: 2>]
z = Status.data(8) # z <- []
```

Would it be possible to customize "return by value" of `IntEnum` without breaking anything? Since there will be multiple classes that will extend the `Bits` class, ideally this functionality should be implemented in the `Bits` class.

What I want to achieve is this:

```
x = Status(3) # x <- [<Status.READY: 0>, <Status.ERROR: 1>]
y = Status(4) # y <- [<Status.WARNING: 2>]
z = Status(8) # z <- []
```

I tried overriding the `__call__` method (see [enum — Support for enumerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#)), but it does not seem to be called in this case.

Comment: That is a complete misuse of `IntEnum`. Why are you not using `IntFlags`?

Comment: Also I assume you overrode `__call__` on the type, but that defines calling *instances*,  if you read the documentation you linked it specifies that you need to override it on the *metaclass*. A more common and supported way to customise initialisation is to override `__new__`.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation to use `IntFlag`, but the problem would be the same. Using a _metaclass_ did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could customize the return value of an `IntEnum` class by defining a custom `__new__` method for your `Status` class, this way it will change the behavior of how new instances are created without breaking the functionality of the IntEnum.

```
from enum import IntEnum, EnumMeta

class BitsMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __call__(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            return [e for e in cls if (1 << e.value) & value]
        return super().__call__(value)

class Bits(IntEnum, metaclass=BitsMeta):

    @classmethod
    def data(cls, value: int):
        return [e for e in cls if (1 << e.value) & value]

class Status(Bits):
    READY = 0
    ERROR = 1
    WARNING = 2

x = Status(3)  # x <- [<Status.READY: 0>, <Status.ERROR: 1>]
y = Status(4)  # y <- [<Status.WARNING: 2>]
z = Status(8)  # z <- []

print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
```

Comment: Have you tried running this? I get `TypeError` exception. Also, this functionality needs to be added to the `Bits` class because there will be multiple classes just like the `Status` class.

Comment: I modified my answer with the Bits class extension in mind

Comment: Thanks, using a metaclass did the trick! As for the `__call__` method, can I omit  `super().__call__()`? Would it be safe to have something like this: `return [ ... ] if isinstance(value, int) else None`?

Comment: You welcome, yes you can replace it with None but its generally better to keep the super().__call__() so that you can use both the custom functionality and the normal enum functionality

Comment: @MarkoGulin -- is the `data` method even needed now?

Comment: @EthanFurman It is not needed. Body of my `class Bits` has only `pass`, but I might add more logic to it in the future (e.g., R/W access flags on a bit-level).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you need to use `x`, `y`, and `z`, `IntFlag` may work for you:

```
class Status(IntFlag):
    READY = 0
    ERROR = 1
    WARNING = 2

x = Status(3)
repr(x)
# <Status.ERROR|WARNING: 3>

Status.Error in x
# True

list(x)
# [<Status.Error: 1>, <Status.Warning: 2>]
```

This also seems more correct, since `Status.READY` shouldn't be part of `Status(3)`, and `Status.WARNING` should be.

---

Looking closer, I see your values are actually bit positions -- so while the `value` attribute of `Status.READY` is `0`, it's considered set if `1` is passed in... I can see that being confusing.

Here's how I would do it:

```
class Status(IntFlag, boundary=CONFORM):
    READY = auto()
    ERROR = auto()
    WARNING = auto()

x = Status(3)
repr(x)
# <Status.READY|ERROR: 3>
```

The `CONFORM` boundary means out-of-range values are ignored (like `8` in your OP).

The difference now between my solution and yours is the value shown for a single member:

```
# mine
<Status.READY: 1>

# yours
<Status.READY: 0>
```

You'll have to decide which version makes more sense in your environment.

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Oh nice! When Masklinn first proposed to use `IntFlag` in their comment to my question, I thought it does not inherently "decompose" an integer value to flags. Now I see it does. It makes more sense to use `IntFlag` in this particular example, in which case I do not need `BitMeta` _metaclass_ anymore. I'll still keep Saxtheowl's answer as accepted because it directly addresses the question :) Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: @MarkoGulin, no worries!  I also updated my answer with another example and some comments.

Comment: `IntFlag` is definitely an excellent fit for my application. `enum` is very powerful tool, well done for developing it!!! :)) Is there a way to define that assigned values are treated as a bit (flag) position? Something similar to `boundary=CONFORM` directive? I now I can override the `__new__` method to implement this functionality, but I was wondering is there something native.

Comment: @MarkoGulin: There is nothing native for bit positions.